# Ruby wrapper for the deprecated Google search API

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-search-api

I'm looking for the best ruby wrapper for [the deprecated Google Web Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/docs/#Introduction). Anyone know of a good one with good documentation? Examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you move to the new API? http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html

Comment: I want to be able to search the entire web.

Answer (score 1):

I've stumbled upon this handy little gem for Bing that may help you out - [RBing](http://9astronauts.com/code/ruby/rbing/).

So far I've not been able to track down a better solution for searching the entire web via Google beyond scraping them for their results since they have deprecated their API.